# script for zipping the files with 10 days back files in one folder in unix?

Tags: unix

i am trying to zip log files by using "zip " command in UNIX server.
but i want to zip 10 days before files automatically,with out changing the command manually. can any one suggest the script for zipping the files with 10 days back files in one folder.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [find](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?find) command and use zip command to do this like the following

```
find . -name '*.log' -mtime +10 | zip logfiles.zip -@
```

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative:

```
find . -iname '*.log' -mtime +9 -exec zip logfiles.zip {} +
```

You will probably want to use the `-m` option of zip which will delete the logs after zipping them.

```
find . -iname '*.log' -mtime +9 -exec zip -m logfiles.zip {} +
```

**How does it work?**

`find .` will find files starting in the current directory.

`-iname '*.log'` filters the files ending in .log, .LOG, .Log, etc

`-mtime +9` will select the files that were modified at least 9 days before today, i.e: 10 days ago.

`-exec zip -m logfiles.zip {} +` will run the zip -m logfiles.zip file1 file2 file3 ... and so on.

`zip -m file.zip file` zips file into file.zip and deletes file.

**Some other options**:

Probably you want to run this script a couple of times, so, you can use a variable for your logfiles like the date expressed in mm.dd.yyyy format:

```
find . -iname '*.log' -mtime +9 -exec zip -m logfiles-$(date +%m.%d.%Y).zip {} +
```

If you just want to use the logs for the current directory (and not it's subdirectory), you can use the `-maxdepth` option of find:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -iname '*.log' -mtime +9 -exec zip -m logfiles-$(date +%m.%d.%Y).zip {} +
```

Suppose that you have something like:

```
app1/logs/log1.log
app1/logs/log2.log
app2/logs/log1.log
app2/logs/log2.log
```

with `-execdir` (instead of `-exec`) the zip command will be executed for each subdirectory in which it finds files.

So:

```
find . -iname '*.log' -mtime +9 -execdir zip -m logfiles.zip {} +
```

Will leave you with:

```
app1/logs/logfiles.zip --> (contains log1 and log2 from app1/log)
app2/logs/logfiles.zip --> (contains log1 and log2 from app2/log)
```